# How to avoid left margin introduced by \subfloat?

Tags: subfloats

How do I get rid of the left margin introduced by `\subfloat`?

I am using it to stack several plots under a single figure, but the resulting added margin at the left makes the stacked figures look misaligned w.r.t other figures in my text (where I don't use the `\subfloat`). Please find below a minimum example (notice I want to maximize the widths of all the plots, thus the use of `width=1.0\linewidth` everywhere).

Thanks and regards,

Jorge.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent{}This is a single figure without using \textbackslash{}subfloat:

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,frame]{test.eps}
\end{figure}

\noindent{}This is the same figure twice, using \textbackslash{}subfloat:

\begin{figure}[!h]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}
\centering
    \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,frame]{test.eps}
    }
\\
    \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,frame]{test.eps}
    }
\end{figure}

\noindent{}Notice the left margin added by \textbackslash{}subfloat!!! How do I get rid of it???

\end{document}
```

[image: Results of above code:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
    \subfloat[]{%    <---
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,frame]{test.eps}%  <---
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[]{%   <----
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth,frame]{test.eps}%  <---
    }
```

otherwise you'll get some trailing spaces.